# Possible to avoid repeating struct name in an 'impl' functions body?

Tags: rust

It's possible to use `Self` within an `impl` block:

```
impl SomeStruct {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        SomeStruct { foo: 1, bar: 1, }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to refer to the type within the function body? For example:

```
impl SomeStruct {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { foo: 1, bar: 1, }
    //  ^^^^ not recognized, possibly there is some alternative?
    }
}
```

This isn't essential, just handy to be able to avoid repeating long struct names when it can be inferred. It may be useful for generated code too.

Comment: The error clearly states "`Self` and associated types in struct expressions and patterns are unstable (see issue #37544)" - this question seems redundant.

Comment: @ljedrz as a non-expert - for all I know this is some totally different way to achieve this without `Self`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since **Rust 1.16** your code compiles just fine! The `Self` keyword can now be used in more positions, including struct expressions and `impl` header.

Relevant links:

- [Changelog for 1.16](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#language-2)
- [PR stabilizing the feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/39282)
- [The tracking-issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37544)
- [My previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41651393/1)